# Serializing an HTML form into a JS Object with data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've been using this to take a form and serialize the contents into a JS Object (not JSON).

https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

The problem is that it doesn't support serializing `data-` values. There are times when I want ONE form input to have an object as a value, and the only way I can think to do that is to store the object into the `data-` attribute on the input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedProducts[]" data-value="{ sku: 'item1', price: 2599 }">
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedProducts[]" data-value="{ sku: 'item2', price: 999 }">` 

<select>
    <option data-value='{"name":"Sam","age":"40", "isMarried": true}'>Sam</option>
    <option data-value='{"name":"Todd","age":"22", "isMarried": false}'>Todd</option>
</select>
```

It's easy enough to do it manually with jQuery, but I have a lot of forms and frankly it's a pain to do it without a package.

Comment: The question is why? What possible reason would there be for a checkbox to have an object associated with it, that has to be sent somewhere, when all it's supposed to be is checked or unchecked? This sounds a lot like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Why not? Ok, maybe `<checkbox>` isn't a good example. How about `<option>`?

Comment: It might not be as convenient but you could try using , separated values instead of an object then just turn it into an array when it passes through the JavaScript you need

Comment: Options aren't really serialized, only the select is. It should be quite easy to write something that returns the name, value and data-attributes for form elements, but how do you intend to use it? All webservers generally know how to process `x-form-urlencoded` where only a name and value is passed, for instance in PHP you'd do `$_POST[name]` and get the value, but it has no idea how to parse additional data, you'd have to send that data as something else, and write something on the server that is able to parse it etc.

Comment: Sure seems like you are over complicating whatever higher level issue you are trying to solve. What is the higher level use case for all this?

Comment: I'm not sending the data anywhere. If you look at the link to the script I linked to in the OP, you'll see that it takes a form and turns the contents into a JS Object. That's all I want to do - get the form contents into a JS Object, of any configuration.

Comment: It's simple. You either decide to store the data somewhere on the DOM directly, or have the DOM be a value which you then use to look up / create the right data values in JS code. I'm choosing to just do the former. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Well you will now have to either extend that plugin or do the lookups yourself or add event handlers to build the data

Comment: Well, here's how to do it -> **https://jsfiddle.net/16895emz/**